# Post Method not allowed in CBV dispatch when form is invalid

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

When creating a view using FormView class and using dispatch method to fetch some data during class initialization,  Error is received when the form gets invalid

```
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Method "POST" not allowed.', code='method_not_allowed')}
```

here is the code :-

```
class TestView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = TestForm
    template_name = 'test.html'

   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = TestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})(self.request).data
        return super(TestView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CredentialsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            context['username'] = self.data['username']
            context['firstname'] = self.data['firstname']
            context['lastname'] = self.data['lastname']
            
        return context

        
    def form_valid(self, form):
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.query_api(password)
        else:
            return super(TestView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Here is the trace :-

> django: {'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Method "POST" not allowed.',
> code='method_not_allowed')} Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 34, in inner response = get_response(request) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 115, in _get_response response =
> self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 113, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request,
> *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
> line 71, in view return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py",
> line 52, in dispatch return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
> line 97, in dispatch return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) File
> "./ssh/views.py", line 91, in post return self.form_invalid(form,
> **kwargs) File "./ssh/views.py", line 77, in form_invalid context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs) File "./ssh/views.py", line 97, in
> get_context_data kwargs['username'] = data['username'] KeyError:
> 'username'

How can we initialize the view in above scenario in order to set the data for the context ?

Comment: Well why do you call `TestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})(self.request).data` from your view? That is why you are getting the error. Can you show that viewsets code?

Comment: Viewset is working fine , it is fetching the data from the serializer in the background , dispatch throws error when form gets invalid , i am trying to set context to the template , expectation was to set the context when the form is invalid as well and return the form errors alongside , which is not happening in the above case , context gets invalid somehow when form becomes invalid , but works fine when form is valid.

Comment: Your viewset works for _GET_ requests, you are passing it a _POST_ request... what I want to say is _why_ call the viewset just use the serializer in your own view...

Comment: Well the api was already written with viewsets , i am using already created viewset to fetch data rather than repeating the code in the view , well i thought the dispatch method worked for both get and post on the view.

Comment: That call to viewset is a get call on the list method of the viewset , the post not allowed error is probably coming from the form class , when the form is invalid